# cocoa podsを使ってライブラリのインストール方法

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoapods, unix

現在、アプリをobjective-cで作成していましてcocoa podsでプロジェクトフォルダにライブラリをインストールしたいのですが、困っていることがあります。
内容としてはプロジェクトを数個使ってアプリを作成している場合、すべてのプロジェクトに対してライブラリを一度にインストールすることは可能でしょうか？
また、ライブラリをインストールした後に違うライブラリをインストールするときはどうすればいいですか？

宜しくお願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## 複数プロジェクトの依存記述

Podfile 中で、プロジェクトごとにターゲットを設定、そこでそれぞれの依存関係を記述するという方法が取れそうです。
複数プロジェクトで同じライブラリをインストールしたいのであれば、プロジェクト毎のターゲットで同じライブラリを依存として記述すれば良いはず。

まず、以下のように複数のプロジェクト（.xcodeprojファイル）と Podfile が同一ディレクトリにあると仮定します：

```
<proj_root>─┬─Project1.xcodeproj
            ├─Project2.xcodeproj
            └─Podfile
```

上記のファイル構成の場合、Podfile は以下のようにします：

```
workspace 'MyWorkspace'
xcodeproj 'Project1.xcodeproj'

target :Project1 do
platform :ios, '6.0'
pod 'AFNetworking'
xcodeproj 'Project1.xcodeproj'
end

target :Project2 do
platform :ios, '6.0'
pod 'AFNetworking'
xcodeproj 'Project2.xcodeproj'
end
```

- Podfileリファレンス (英): https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html
- 「How do I specify multiple targets and projects in my podfile for my Xcode project?」: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20875561/328640

## ライブラリを差し替える際のステップ

`pod install`などを実行すると Pods というディレクトリが作成されますが、それを削除することをお勧めします。
その上で、Podfile の記述を変更して `pod install` を実行するといいと思います（`pod update`ではなく）。

Comment: 丁寧な回答ありがとうございました。おかげで解決ができてとても感謝です。